# Zendesk Sell/Base CRM Contacts API Create/POST returns 500 Unknown Error

Tags: crm

When I call Zendesk Sell (formerly Base CRM) Contacts API to create a new employee-contact (POST), I get error "500 Unknown Error".

Answer (score 1):

This is an undocumented property. The title-fields max length is 250 characters. If you try to enter a longer title for the employee, you get the 500 Unknown Error.

In Ruby my solution was to slice the title-field to 250 characters:

```
crm_client.contacts.create(
          first_name: formatted_name[:firstname],
          last_name: formatted_name[:lastname],
          title: employee.job_title.slice(0, 250),
          contact_id: company_id
      )
```